# Set all the <li> to have the same width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, width, html-lists

I want to build a `navbar` with bootstrap which all the cell in it will have the same width.

I tried the code above, but it doesn't work well.
How can I fix it?

```
.navbar-collapse {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

.navbar .nav {
    margin: 0;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    direction: rtl;
}

.navbar .nav > li {
    float: right;
    display: table-cell;
    width: auto;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    direction: rtl;
}
.navbar .nav > li:hover {
background-color: #808080
}

.navbar .nav li:first-child a {
    border-left: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.navbar .nav li:last-child a {
    border-right: 0;
    border-radius: 0 333px 3px 0;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/abzvw0m3/ (when screen width is bigger than 768 px)

Comment: A set width, the same width as the widest li, or something else? Also... why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

changed it to this,all li elements will have 10% width of its parent.

```
.navbar .nav > li {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    direction: rtl;
    width:10%;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To have the same cell width, you must set on the `ul.nav` the rule `table-layout: fixed;`

```
.navbar .nav {
    margin: 0;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    direction: rtl;
    table-layout: fixed; 
}

.navbar ul.nav  li {
    float: right;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    direction: rtl;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/abzvw0m3/14/)**

Comment: Thanks, but then the <li> are not have all the width of the nav's width. There's some padding that is unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

try with  adding the width

```
.navbar .nav > li {
float: right;
display: table-cell;
width: auto;
float: none;
text-align: center;
direction: rtl;
width: 15%;;    /* add the width use % for dinamic**/
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want it to be dynamic and not static

Answer (score 0):

Change your li to have a fixed width or percentage width of a value similar to that of the largest li you will be using,

for instance:

```
width: 132px;
```

or

```
width: 20%;
```